# beginner's questions about web app (MS tech)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am about to launch web app (start-up), myself not coder nor tech-friendly. The app is being developed using asp.net 4.0 (VB.net), jQuery, json, xml, SQL Server 2008. It is currently programmed by developers i hired. my questions are..

1. What is process from coding to deploying at server? (with explanations of what each tech above does)? Brief, easy explanation will help me understand the flow.
2. Later on after the app goes live, do I still need to use same IDE used initially?
3. I hear Microsoft techs are expensive to run (some disagree though..). What are some expected cost and fees running the platform built with MS tech?

These are very very basic questions and I am sorry to bother you but your helps will be very much appreciated... I figured out books don't help a lot..

Lastly, is there any book or source for person like myself?

Answer (score 2):

> Q: I am about to launch web app (start-up), myself not coder nor
>   tech-friendly... It is currently programmed by developers i hired.

A: Friendly bit of advice: you *DON'T CARE* if it's written in XML, Json, C++, Java or Sanskrit.  You don't care what (if any!) IDE is used, or whether you'll still use it after delivery.

You *ONLY* care whether or not the developers are going to give you the product you need, and whether they're going to do it on-time and within budget.

The key to any successful software project is 1) capturing, and 2) managing a good set of "software requirements".  There are many "methodologies" for doing this ("Agile development", "Scrum", "Extreme Programming", etc etc).  You *DON'T CARE* about any of this, either.

Focus on "what am I building"?  Know that *you* know what you want.  Then make sure your *team* knows what you want.

Then *you* can focus on all the *other* things you need to do for your startup to be successful.

Suggested reading:

- http://www.cio.com/article/29903/Five_Things_IT_Managers_Should_Know_About_Software_Requirements
- http://pragprog.com/book/prj/ship-it
- http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703467004575463460389523660.html

Comment: I suppose that would be true if a web app was inert and never needed to change or be updated (hello, security updates?) but given that's not the nature of a web app, I think it's kinda silly to say those things don't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) and those readings and book seem very helpful to me. again thank you very much.

Comment: @user2074048 - my pleasure.  And again: your job is make sure you're getting what you need.  Technical minutiae like "Java vs .Net" or "XML vs JSON" is basically a pimple on a gnat's rump.  They do *not* make or break a project.  IMHO...